# Bootstrap Modal Loading but Non-Responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've read the many threads on this topic but none have answered the issue that I'm having.  I am trying to create a modal view overlay that spans the page width. However, the modal renders but it isn't responsive. It is darkened out and buttons won't work. This is how I load my assets:

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core -->
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link rel='stylesheet' href='styles/application.css'>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And this the code I'm running on modal:

```
</head>
  <body>
    <!--  Modal    -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <h3>Modal Body</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is where I want it called from. And I think because I have an animation effect it might be screwing with the event. Note that this is the first thing within the yield:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><h1>Title</h1></div>
          <div class="row">     
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="menu-item-1 card effect_hover">  
                <a class="modal-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal">
                  <div class="card_front">
                    <span class="icon-home3 card_text"></span><br>ABOUT
                  </div>
                <div class="card_back">
                  <span class="card_text">Learn all about our community!</span> 
                </div>
               </a>
              </div>
             ...
```

So, that's it. I've read the Documentation by Bootstrap and have copied the code into the page but the same issue remains. I've also tried using a local version of bootstrap assets.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to create a modal view overlay that spans the page width.

Well in that case, you'll have to edit the below line of CSS in the bootstrap.css (not recommended) or in your custom css file.

Here's the line:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    width: 100%;    // by default its 600px.
    margin: 30px auto;
  }
```

The Bootstrap carousel is built to be responsive, see the screen shots:

On big screens:

[image: On bigger screen].

On smaller screens:

[image: On smaller screens]

You must be having some content inside the modal which is not responsive or rather with a fixed width.

if you have a look at the styles for the modal, in [bootstrap.css](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L5758), you'll see that:

```
.modal-dialog {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

The width is set to auto except when the screen-width is 768 or greater, in which case the width is set to.

```
width:600px;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Do you have any idea why the buttons wouldn't work on the modal?  They have the required attributes but the screen is still darkened (including the modal view) and the cancel won't exit out of the view.

Comment: @user3162553 , There are 3 ways to close the modal , once its poped up , 1. click on the close button , 2. click on the close 'x' mark , 3. click on the semi transparent black background(this can be disabled by passing in backdrop: `static`   )

Comment: Actually, the effect I'm after is just a full screen overlay.  I was thinking modal was a solution but maybe there's a better one.

Comment: That's the problem - the close button and the 'x' mark are not responding to any clicks.  that's why I believe it is a script issue. I just don't know where that issue is.

Comment: @user3162553, Well the overlay that u see is nothing but this http://jsfiddle.net/zd5vx61u/ , except its added dynamically through Jquery .

Comment: @user3162553 , you gotta have 3 things in place . 1. Import the Jquery , 2. Import the bootstrap.js file .. (Check in your resources that you're actually loading the files .) 3. have the correct markup for the modal (very important )

Comment: You forgot the # , data-target="#basicModal" on your button , should work fine after that fix. also the modal seems to be appearing below the backdrop in your example , tell me if thats the case on your end too .

Comment: In ur stylesheet , have the following declaration `.modal.in .modal-dialog{z-index:9999; }` and also fix the #on the button .